# How to create an external css and how to call it in a component?

Tags: angular

Hiii,I want to create an external css and make it call into a component.The below code only i gave but it show some error that also i have mentioned below.Check it and tell me were i made a mistake and solution for that.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'; 
    @Component({
      templateUrl: './admin.html',
       styleUrls: ['./app/admin/admin.css']

    })
    export class AdminComponent {
      constructor() {
      //  console.log('Admin Component');
      }
    }
```

Error

> ERROR in ./src/app/admin/admin.component.ts Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve './app/admin/admin.css' in '/home/volumata/App
>   UI/7-5-18/EagleTru_May072018/src/app/admin'

Answer (score 0):

Since you are providing relative path, it will not work. You should provide absolute path. Like below.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'; 
    @Component({
      templateUrl: './admin.html',
       styleUrls: ['app/admin/admin.css']

    })
    export class AdminComponent {
      constructor() {
      //  console.log('Admin Component');
      }
    }
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your relative path is wrong. Assuming that your css is at the same place as your component.ts, your relative path need to be as the following:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './admin.html',
   styleUrls: ['./admin.css']

})
```